# Transmitting SD Card Communication sequence on STM32f103 with Hal Driver

Tags: sd-card, spi, hal

I am writing a SD Card low level driver to implement Chan's FATFS System on a Olimex MOD-MP3-X board with a STM32f103rb processor. I'm pretty new to this topic at all and I am no native english speaker, but i hope i can point out my problem.
At first I want to write a function to send the cmd commands via SPI.
So i got this Prototype for the function usage:

```
static void sd_cmd(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg);
```

//I already found the HAL-command to transmit the data:

HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size);

//But I don't know exactly how put the Argument and the cmd into the data buffer.

//I already tried by creating an array, but this didn't work:

```
uint8_t buffer[5];
uint8_t buffer[0]= 0x40 | cmd;
uint8_t buffer[1]= arg >> 24;
uint8_t buffer[2]= arg >> 16;
uint8_t buffer[3]= arg >> 8;
uint8_t buffer[4]= arg;
```

...

HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi2, &buffer, 5);